# Account Recovery link ends up with Page Not Found

Tags: support, unregistered-users, account-recovery

I tried to recover an unregistered account. The link with "Visit this page to restore your account cookie" provided in the e-mail forwards me to https://stackoverflow.com/users/restore-cookie// that returns a "page not found" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try issuing the request again -- the tickets are time sensitive, so this can happen if you wait too long before clicking the link in the email.