# SO login using normal registered ID

Tags: support, login

It seems now I can only login using an open ID, like what I am now doing.

But I want to login to SO using my previously registered ID, a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

When not logged in, then on [the login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login), you'll see a link:

> If you've forgotten or lost your login information
>   [click here to recover your account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery)

This will bring you to [a page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) on which you can enter your email address. Then, in your email, follow the link to "Visit this page to restore your account cookie". Note that this link is valid [for a limited time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70029/account-recovery-link-ends-up-with-page-not-found/70030#70030).

Still then, you probably want your accounts to be merged. For that, [send an email to team@stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste), specifying as many details as possible, like all the URLs of your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Although it is possible to create an account that doesn't have any openid associated with it, the only way the system knows who you are is through your cookies.

Once those cookies are lost there is no way to log back in into that account. At any moment you can complete the registration process by attaching an openid to the account, so that you don't run into this problem.

If you want you can flag one of your posts for moderator attention and ask your accounts to be merged.

Comment: Cookies can be restored, [right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70029/account-recovery-link-ends-up-with-page-not-found)?